# How to execute command alias, saved as a string variable in a zsh function?

Tags: zsh, function, fzf

I have a function

```bsh
fz(){file=$(find | fzf) && echo $file && read order && $("$order" "$file")}
```

in my `.zshrz`. It allows me to look up for a file anywhere in a subdirectory relative of where I call it from, and then apply a command specified by my input to that file.

Only there's a slight problem: while the function works as intended if `$order` is anything but an alias specifed in the same `.zshrc` file, it shoots a "command not found" should I use any of my aliases.

Is there a way to use aliases stored as variables within zsh functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eval` instead of `$( … )`. This works:

```bsh
fz() {
  file=$( find | fzf )
  echo $file
  read order
  eval "$order $file"
}
```